# Edit errors in topomerge either programmatically or manually

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm following along with Mike Bostocks latest tutorial on [topojson at the command line](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-3-1158e4c55a1e#.oyoiphntw).  Everything seems to be working appropriately, and when I merge shapes, things work, but because there are small errors between edges in orginal shape files, I don't get proper merging.  Specifically, I am trying to merge countries to create continents.  I understand and I'm sure I can probably find a specific continent shape file, but I testing out a process allow the creation of bespoke regions that can be created.

The error I am seeing can be show below:

[image]

Angola is not being merged with the surrounding countries, and I am not sure why.

Does anyone have experience manipulating features like this to get proper merging?

Here is bash script I created for this example (raw shape data can be downloaded [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/)):

```
shp2json ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp -o world-countries.geojson

geostitch world-countries.geojson | geoproject 'd3.geoKavrayskiy7()' > world-countries-projected.geojson

ndjson-split 'd.features' < world-countries-projected.geojson > world-countries.ndjson

ndjson-map 'd.title = d.properties.adm0_a3, d.id = d.properties.adm0_a3, d.continent = d.properties.continent, d' < world-countries.ndjson > world-countries-id.ndjson

geo2svg -n -w 960 -h 960 < world-countries-id.ndjson > world-countries2.svg

geo2topo -n countries=world-countries-id.ndjson > world-countries.topojson

toposimplify -p 2 -f < world-countries.topojson > world-countries-simple.topojson

topoquantize 1e5 < world-countries-simple.topojson > world-countries-quantized.topojson

topomerge -k 'd.continent' continents=countries < world-countries-quantized.topojson > world-continents.topojson

# topomerge --mesh -f 'a !== b' continent=continent < world-continents-merge.topojson > world-continents.topojson

topo2geo continents=world-continents.geojson < world-continents.topojson

geo2svg -w 960 -h 960 < world-continents.geojson > world-continents.svg
```

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error, I found the [Countries without boundary lakes](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes.zip), created better merge boundaries, as can seen below:

[image]

My full script is here:

```
shp2json ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp -o world-countries.geojson

geostitch world-countries.geojson | geoproject 'd3.geoKavrayskiy7()' > world-countries-projected.geojson

ndjson-split 'd.features' < world-countries-projected.geojson > world-countries.ndjson

ndjson-map 'd.title = d.properties.adm0_a3, d.id = d.properties.adm0_a3, d.continent = d.properties.continent, d' < world-countries.ndjson > world-countries-id.ndjson

geo2svg -n -w 960 -h 960 < world-countries-id.ndjson > world-countries2.svg

geo2topo -n countries=world-countries-id.ndjson > world-countries.topojson

toposimplify -p 2 -f < world-countries.topojson > world-countries-simple.topojson

topoquantize 1e5 < world-countries-simple.topojson > world-countries-quantized.topojson

topomerge -k 'd.continent' continents=countries < world-countries-quantized.topojson > world-continents.topojson

topo2geo continents=world-continents.geojson < world-continents.topojson

ndjson-split 'd.features' < world-continents.geojson > world-continents.ndjson

ndjson-map 'd.title = d.id, d' < world-continents.ndjson > world-continents-title.ndjson

geo2svg -n -w 960 -h 960 < world-continents-title.ndjson > world-continents.svg
```